# "{Motion}" Data tag where the player is facing

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How can i summon an entity and shoot it where the player is facing. 
Like shooting an arrow in front of me.

Comment: Good news, this is now possible! I voted to close this question as a duplicate of one where there's already a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You can't.

There is currently no way to simply store values such as player facing directly and use them to set anything.

Therefore, the only way to fire a projectile in the direction the player is facing is by running a separate command for every possible facing of the player using the `rym`, `ry`, `rzm` and `rz` target selector arguments.

```
/execute @a[rym=0,ry=5,rz=0,rzm=5] ~ ~ ~ <command>
/execute @a[rym=5,ry=10,rz=0,rzm=5] ~ ~ ~ <command>
...
/execute @a[rym=0,ry=5,rz=5,rzm=10] ~ ~ ~ <command>
/execute @a[rym=5,ry=10,rz=5,rzm=10] ~ ~ ~ <command>
...
```

This requires a very/forbiddingly high amount of command blocks. Even with only 10 degrees precision, you will need 180/10 * 360/10 = 648 different command blocks. At 5 degrees, it's 2592.

Comment: Good news, this is now possible! I voted to close this question as a duplicate of one where there's already a complete answer.