# How can I summon an entity with motion relative to where I'm facing?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So for a while now, I've been trying how to figure this out ever since the new '^ ^ ^ ' command was introduced. I've always done research but I wasn't able to find something reliable or something I was looking for.

An example of what I mean by this question is something like dropping an axe and having an invisible armor stand, decorated with the axe, fly in the direction I was facing. Simply put, just being able to fire a moving projectile relative to where the player is facing.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I want to note that there is [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235302/motion-data-tag-where-the-player-is-facing) and [this question(https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/287698/how-can-i-summon-an-object-in-motion-where-a-player-is-looking), but they both do not necessarily apply to 1.13. So this question is not a duplicate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've done this exact thing, but I don't know anymore how I did it. I think it comes down to going some distance into your viewing direction, then subtracting positions. I might still have the command blocks around somewhere in my testing world. Good question!

Comment: Nope, I don't have them anymore. Seems like I did that in a copy of my test world that no longer exists. I often reset stuff there are load backups. So I'll start over…

Comment: I knew it! So many things seemed familiar, I was sure I had done this on this site before. It just didn't show up in any sensible search. When I used the query "is:answer user:171580 Pos" (because of the "`Pos`" NBT tag), I finally found it: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/339637 So yes, this is indeed a duplicate, but still a very good post, because as my failed searches show, an additional question with different wording that points towards that question can be very helpful for the future. What a shame, this would have made a great 333rd answer for me. :D

Comment: Oh, that's great, thank you! Does this allow for no gravity though? Basically meaning that it'll go in the direction I'm facing without going any higher or lower. If not, is there any reliable method to do so?

Comment: Sure, just leave out the y axis part, set it to 0 and give it `NoGravity:1`.

Comment: So I've been testing some things out, I checked out the question that was linked. Did some more research and ended up finding this [video] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Df75vdRs7y4). I haven't been able to use the no gravity tag without it stopping the armor stand dead in it's tracks using both methods. It doesn't move in the slightest and only faces the direction I'm looking. Any ideas left? I've messed around with the values I thought would count and I'm not seeing any changes.

Comment: Armour stands don't move on their own, you need to teleport them over and over. If you give them momentum, they will slow down over time, even with `NoGravity`.